# Offline even though network connection test passed

Tags: wii-u

Wii U network connection is set up and it passes the network connection test.  But, during the game Splatoon, the guy says I'm offline.  Is there something i'm supposed to do to connect it even after setting up the connection and passing the test?

Comment: By chance, did you close out of the game before doing the connection test?  I've had a similar issue, but closing and reopening the game fixed it for me.